# Equation having sqrt ,abs and the derivative on c

Tags: c, derivative, sqrt

First, i would like to tell you that english isnt my nature language so maybe a word or meaning i am not express it right.The problem now is i recently did one exercise and the question was to use the  Newton-Raphson method for sqrt.Anyway, i think this(sqrt) i have done it i am not sure about it.I couldnt do the derivative.Also,i think i have some  mistakes on my code if you could fix it i would be greatful.The equation is

> `x=sqrt(num)=>x*x=num=>f(x,num)=x*x-num=0`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> /* i use it for pow */
#definde f(x) ((x*x-num)/2x) /* this is the equation */
main(){
double num=8; /* i put what ever i want so i put 8 */
double result;
double oldx=2; /* i put what ever i want so i chose to put 2 */
double x;
x=num/2;
result=sqrt(x);
printf("num= %d x= %16.lf\n",num,result);
while(abs(x-oldx)>pow(10,-15)){ /* |x-oldx|> pow(10,-15).I am not sure about       abs here */
     x=oldx; /* i give to x the price of oldx */
     printf("x=%lf",x); /* its double so i use lf */
     x=(pow(x,2)-num)/2*x;  /* #definde f(x) ((x*x-num)/2x) this is it but i   wrote it in that way.Maybe i dont know it could be false */
     printf("x=%lf",x);
     }
printf("x= %lf result= % 16.lf ");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: i think i understand what you mean.Give me a moment

Comment: its better now?

Comment: Yes, somewhat better. With some blank lines at strategic places it would be even better.

Comment: You have numerous bugs - watch out for operator precedence (there are places where you need additional parentheses) - also you need to use `fabs`, not `abs` (`abs` works with integers).

Comment: If you for my code i tried to do it.If you talking about the exercise it tells to use it only the Newton-Raphson for sqrt.Sorry i didnt know .Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @MichaelWalz: sorry - that's what I meant, but a couple of neurons mis-fired.

Comment: @e.p.: Please don't edit the code in the question to incorporate suggested fixes - this makes the question less useful to future visitors, as the comments/answers no longer make sense.

Comment: ok sorry. I will put it again abs

Comment: You can replace `pow(10,-15)` with a constant `1e-15`, and replace `pow(x,2)` with `x*x`.

Comment: 1e-15 what it is ?

Comment: Scientific notation of a number in some language

Comment: The way you describe the maths doesn't make sense to me, so I cannot say whether your algorithm is correct mathematically. However, there is a bug in the translation from formula to code.  `x=(pow(x,2)-num)/2*x;` has the last `x` in the numerator. You should use either: `x=(pow(x,2)-num)/2/x;` or `x=(pow(x,2)-num)/(2*x);`

Comment: Since you have a lot of simple mistakes in the code I'm going to give you my standard advice on learning to use a debugger: *It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).*

Comment: @e.p [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) which is used in almost every programming language. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant

Comment: If its not problem with you or someone else how could be the derivative?i should declare it #define again ?how to use it on my  program?its like a method i call it as java from a class that i have a method and i call this  method to my main?could you do as an answer because i cant catch it or an example because i cant find nothing.@Paul R i use it on java debbuger not in c.I think only java had this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous mistakes in your code:

1. `abs` should be `fabs`.
2. The `while` loop keeps setting `x=oldx` for each iteration and `oldx` never changes, so the loop never makes any progress.  It should really set `oldx=x`.
3. `/2*x` does not divide by `2*x` as you require, because `*` and `/` have the same operator precedence. You need to replace it with `/(2*x)` or `/2/x`.
4. At each step, you are calculating *xₙ₊₁* = *f(xₙ)* / *fʹ(xₙ)*, but the correct formula is *xₙ₊₁* = *xₙ* − *f(xₙ)* / *fʹ(xₙ)*.

In addition, there is no need to use the `pow` function to calculate 10⁻¹⁵ or *x*² when a literal constant or a simple multiplication will do.

Here is a complete solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double num = 8; /* i put what ever i want so i put 8 */
    double result;
    double x;
    double oldx;
    double residual;
    unsigned int iterations=0;

    result = sqrt(num);
    x = num / 2;        /* initial guess */
    printf("sqrt(%g)=%.16g\n", num, result);
    do {
        printf("x%u=%.16g\n", iterations, x);
        iterations++;
        oldx = x;
        x = x - ((x * x - num) / (2 * x));
        residual = x - oldx;
    } while (fabs(residual) > 1e-15);
    printf("x%u=%.16g residual=%.16g\n", iterations, x, residual);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what it is unsigned? and why you dont use #define f'(x) and you throw it like this way,because you use math.h?sorry that i am asking to many question.One more %u and %g?it shouldnt be %16.lf ?

Comment: `unsigned` is for unsigned (non-negative) integers. `%u` is for printing an `unsigned int` value, similar to the way `%d` is used for printing a regular (signed) `int` value. `%g` is another way of printing a `double`. For `printf`, `%lf` is the same as `%f` - they both print a `double` value. (For `scanf`, `%lf` is for `double *` and `%f` is for `float *`, but for `printf` the `float` is promoted to `double` so the `l` is redundant.) The `%.16` specifies the precision of the number to print, whereas `%16` specifies the minimum field width. See the documentation of `printf` for details.

Comment: You can't use `#define f'(x)` because `f'` is not a valid identifier in C. You could have `#define f(x) ((x) * (x) - (num))` and `#define fdx(x) (2 * (x))`, and then use `x = x - f(x) / fdx(x);` in the loop.